# Please help me re-word this sentence

Tags: style

I'm having a hard time formulating a sentence with the following meaning

> Please note that not all eBooks support all the different platforms
>   and devices.

I think the sentence conveys the idea (please mention if it's ambiguous); however, I feel it's unnatural and unprofessional.

I'm looking for suggestions to re-word and improve it. Thank you!

Comment: General critique requests such as this are [off-topic](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/166/26) here. In addition, questions looking to [rephrase a small amount of text](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/535/26) are also off-topic. I'm closing this question, but please feel free to keep asking questions!

Answer (score 3):

> Please note that some eBooks may be unavailable in formats required by certain eBook readers.

- First off, the relation is in opposite direction. Device supports media, not the opposite.
- It's about formats, not the content so, eBook formats.
- A device supports a number of formats, requires any single of them.
- an *eBook reader* covers both devices and programs; mostly all platforms support all formats, providing they can run a program that can read them.
- *not all...all* is less than optimal style. I think "some, certain", "unavailable" is a better word choice.
- I'm still not sure about "certain", you may prefer something like "selected", "chosen" or such.

Answer (score 3):

how about -

> Not all eBooks will be compatible with all operating systems and eReaders.

Answer (score 0):

Each type of eBook reader has different requirements. Not every title will be available for use on a particular reader.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note: some eBooks cannot be viewed on certain platforms or devices.